# How to change clickable property value (at run time) to false of my styleFunc which is given to style attribute of agm-data-layer element?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-google-maps

I am using agm-data-layer like this:

```
<agm-data-layer [geoJson]="geometry.geojson" [style]="styleFunc" (layerClick)="clicked($event, geometry)"> </agm-data-layer>
```

I have given the following styles using:

```
 styleFunc(feature) {
    return ({
      clickable: true,
      fillColor: feature.getProperty('color'),
      strokeColor: '#182C47',
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillOpacity: 0.08,
      zIndex: 0
    });
  }
```

Now in the body of my another function, I want to change its clickable property value to false. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There's no CSS property called "clickable". you might mean `pointerEvents`?

[CSS pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: Here in the example, they are also using the same property "clickable":
https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/agmdatalayer

 styleFunc(feature) {
     return ({
       clickable: false,
       fillColor: feature.getProperty('color'),
       strokeWeight: 1
     });
   }

Answer (score 0):

You can use object spread operator `...` since [TypeScript 2.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html)

```
const obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const obj2 = { 
    ...obj1,
    b: 333,
    c: 444 // compiled to 'var obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1, { b: 333, c: 444 });'
};
console.log(obj2); // a: 1, b: 333, c: 444
```

so you can try:

```
anotherFunc() {
  styleFunc = (feature) => {
    return {
      ...this.styleFunc(feature),
      clickable: false
    };
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you explain that further such that others can learn from your answer?

Comment: Edited, I havent noticed that the desired behavior is to change the `styleFunc` method.